# CSS not included in Webpack bundle with Angular 2

Tags: angular, webpack

I am working with Angular 2 and trying to include a CSS that is referenced inside a component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styleUrls: [
    './app.component.css'
  ],
```

I included the following line in the webpack configuration:

```
   {
        test:  /\.css$/,
        loader: 'to-string-loader!css-loader'
   }
```

However, the css does not apply on the component.

Comment: Couldn't comment, but are you using angular2-template-loader?

Answer (score 0):

You have to refer path from the base root folder..

**For Example** following is my folder structure..

[image]

then my code will look like

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
   templateUrl: 'src/app/sub.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['src/app/app.component.css']

})

export class AppComponent {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 'style-loader' which will put your css file in style tag in your index.html page.

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
},
```

'css-loader' handle your css files and then 'style-loader' put them in the style tag of the page.